# startActivityForResult with createChooser causes chooser window to constantly flicker

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the following code to create a file chooser:

```
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadFile, String acceptType) {
        _uploadFile = uploadFile;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        if (acceptType != null && acceptType.length() > 0) {
            i.setType(acceptType);
        }
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"), Action.FileChooser.ordinal());
    }
```

This works ok on most devices. On some devices, when the `startActivityForResult` is called, the chooser windows pops up, but flickers in front of my app. It's hard to describe, but it is like it is appearing very briefly in front of my app, and then going behind for about a second, then it will appear again. It does this over and over again until you kill the activity. It is completely unusable in this state because you can't see it for long enough to do anything.

Currently I can replicate this reliably on my phone which is Android 4.2.2 but we've seen it on other OS versions as well.

Any suggestions as to how to make this work would be great.

Comment: Since this is not standard behavior for the chooser, presumably there is something in your app that is contributing to the problem. Without a reproducible test case with source, it'll be difficult for anyone to help you unless they happened to encounter the same symptoms.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that might be the case, but right now I'm hoping that someone might have some ideas as to the cause or suggestions as to what is going on

Comment: Got this problem on Intent.createChooser() on my Mi 11 too. The exit animation works fine but the entering animation flickers. However that won't happen on my Pixel 3.